# Twig UTF-8 displaying utf-8 encoded text from doctrine 2

Tags: php, symfony, utf-8, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm having a problem with the displaying of `utf-8` characters in `HTML`. The problem is that I save `utf-8` text in a database and that when i retrieve this with Doctrine (it is still `UTF-8` then, I checked) and output with Twig, the special chars like `ë` becomes `Ã«`. Is there a function in twig that outputs the correct text?

I also added a meta tag for my charset. autoescaping and the raw function in twig have no effect.

Comment: check your response headers for correct charset and report back wether you have `charset=utf-8` in there and inpect your `<head>` tag if it includes something different from `<meta charset="utf-8">`. Further there is a twig [`convert_encoding`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/convert_encoding.html) filter ... or try something like `<p charset="utf-8">{{ db_output }}</p>`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I run getCharset on my response it returns null. I saw on the internet that Symfony, when the charset is not explicitly set, is UTF-8 by default.Even though I set the response charset, the special chars remain 'broken'. The database output is correct. Another website uses the same DB and the content there is correctly displayed. But that is done iwith Silex and not Symfony. The charset definition in the <p> doesn't work either.

Comment: I noticed when I do a utf8_decode on the string it gives the correct output. But this shouldn't be necessary since my charset is on UTF-8 and not ISO-8859-1. Twig doesn't output the string in the right encoding.

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260814/doctrine2-with-symfony2-not-recognizing-db-charset-and-collation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer. Symfony tells Doctrine to use UTF-8 (in the config.yml)

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   %database_driver%
    host:     %database_host%
    port:     %database_port%
    dbname:   %database_name%
    user:     %database_user%
    password: %database_password%
    charset:  UTF8
```

This makes Doctrine do some kind of double encoding. The solution is to comment or remove the charset option in the config:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   %database_driver%
    host:     %database_host%
    port:     %database_port%
    dbname:   %database_name%
    user:     %database_user%
    password: %database_password%
    # charset:  UTF8
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

@wildewouter;
For me, i had to add it to Doctrine:

```
$dbParams = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user' => 'cvakanties_comp',
    'password' => 'xXYXp7bNl',
    'dbname' => 'cvakanties_comp',
    'charset' => 'UTF8',
);
```